# Configure max attribute size with woodstox

Tags: java, xml-parsing, woodstox

The `woodstox-core-asl` for some bizarre reason seems to have a limit on the maximum size of the attribute values to be 512KB. So the XML parsing fails with the error (524288 below is the 512KB limit):

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Maximum attribute size (524288) exceeded
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,898330]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.parseAttrValue(BasicStreamReader.java:1959)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3063)
```

Is there a way to configure this max attribute size or even completely disable it? (Why the attribute value has to be that large is a different argument, though -- and I have to see what I can do about it.)

I tried to look at the source code, but I only have limited access to it -- can't browse github at work. There aren't any pointers in their docs either.

The version of the library I'm using is `4.2.0`. Upgrading the version is possible but even with the newer versions, they seem to have this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to change that. Error message really ought to mention it, but since it does not... let's see. Constants are defined in `WstxInputProperties` (for Woodstox-specific ones, not standard Stax ones) and property you need is `P_MAX_ATTRIBUTE_SIZE`.
To effectively disable check, use value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
Value is change by calling `XMLInputFactory.setProperty` method.

These limits were added to guard against various Denial-of-Service (DoS) attacks: there are a few; you can see ones available in `WstxInputProperties`. Settings are quite conservative and it may well make sense to see if you really need to process 512kB attribute values... :)

Comment: I was looking at those classes -- I was just not sure how to make use of that property. I will give it a try!

Comment: Ok. Stax specs does not have many ways to configure things, so `setProperty()` is pretty much the only way to do anything, config-wise. :)

Answer (score 0):

VM Options

```
-Dxml.ws.maximum.AttributeSize=123456789
```

or Java

```
System.setProperty("xml.ws.maximum.AttributeSize", String.valueOf(123456789));
```